# Updating Objects in state immutably - mandatory or not

Tags: reactjs, immutability

Going through the react beta docs where updating objects in state was discussed. I understand that updating state objects immutably is desired so that react can figure out something's changed and re-render.

This is the original state used in the example:
const [person, setPerson] = useState({
name: 'Niki de Saint Phalle',
artwork: {
title: 'Blue Nana',
city: 'Hamburg',
image: 'https://i.imgur.com/Sd1AgUOm.jpg',
}
});

When trying to changle the title of the artwork, it was mentioned to spread the object and just update the required object property as below:

pl note that commented code was what was shared in the example and the last two lines is what I was experimenting with.

```
function handleTitleChange(e) {
    // setPerson({
    //   ...person,
    //   artwork: {
    //     ...person.artwork,
    //     title: e.target.value
    //   }
    // });
    person.artwork.title = e.target.value // I tried updating it directly
    setPerson({...person}) // trigger a re-render
  }
```

Now what I tried was directly updating the state property and then triggering a re-render by spreading the person object.

I compared the highlighted components when they re-render. It is same in both the case.
I wanted to get opinion as to why we need to particularly follow the wordy spreading of objects and what might be the pitfall if directly updating and triggering a re-render.

Some code examples would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

State immutability is not mandatory, but usually preferable. For complex objects it is important to track nested objects changes.

So, here is what can your code can lead to:

1. useEffect is not triggered due to it has object's nested property as a dependency
2. Memoized component will not be rerendered due to argument reference is not changed

Why is it happening - React is using ReferenceEquality comparison for non-primitives (string, boolean, number) in its change detection strategy. If reference is not changed - rerender and useEffects and other similar things are not executed even if data itself is mutated.

In your current "experimental" code - you are changing the reference of `person` object, but reference of "artwork" inside of it is not changed, artwork is mutated, but reference is preserved:

```js
const {useState, useEffect, memo} = React;

function App() {
  const [person, setPerson] = useState({
    artwork: {
      title: "test"
    }
  });

  function handleTitleChange(e) {
    person.artwork.title = e.target.value;
    setPerson({ ...person });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Artwork changed: ", person.artwork);
  }, [person.artwork]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        value={person.artwork.title}
        onChange={handleTitleChange}
      />
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(person, null, 2)}</pre>
      <TestComponent artwork={person.artwork} />
      <MemoComponent artwork={person.artwork} />
    </div>
  );
}

function TestComponent({artwork}) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Artwork changed in sub-component: ", artwork);
  }, [artwork]);

  return (<p>Artwork title: {artwork.title}</p>);
};

const MemoComponent = memo(TestComponent);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

What you can see here:

1. useEffect in the App component is not triggered after changes
2. useEffect and the UI in `memo` component are not triggered/updated after changes
3. useEffect in non-memo component is not triggered BUT component itself is rerendered with new data.

Comment: Code snippet looks ugly as is by default, so "Run code snippet" => "Full page" to see a bit more.

Comment: this is great Sergey. thanks for the detailed explanation with code snippets. Really appreciate it :)